# Do I need to retrain Bert for NER to create new labels?

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model, fine-tuning

I am very new to natural language processing and I was thinking about working on named entity recognition NER. A friend of mine who works with NLP advised me to check out BERT, which I did. When reading the documentation and checking out the CoNLL-2003 data set, I noticed that the only labels are person, organization, location, miscellanious and outside. What if instead of outside, I want the model to recognize date, time, and other labels. I get that I would need a dataset labelled as such so, assuming that I have that, do I need to retrain BERT from stratch or can I somehow fine tune the existing model without needing to restart the whole process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you would have to use a model trained using the specific labels you require. The [OntoNotes dataset](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2013T19) may be better suited for what you are trying to do, as it includes the 18 entity names listed below (see [OntoNotes 5.0 Release Notes](https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/docs/LDC2013T19/OntoNotes-Release-5.0.pdf) for further info).

The HuggingFace `flair/ner-english-ontonotes-large` ([here](https://huggingface.co/flair/ner-english-ontonotes-large)) and `flair/ner-english-ontonotes-fast` ([here](https://huggingface.co/flair/ner-english-ontonotes-fast)) models are trained on this dataset and will likely produce results closer to what you desire. As a demo (make sure to `pip install flair` first)

```py
from flair.data import Sentence
from flair.models import SequenceTagger

tagger = SequenceTagger.load("flair/ner-english-ontonotes-large")  # load tagger
sentence = Sentence("On September 1st George won 1 dollar while watching Game of Thrones.")  # example sentence
tagger.predict(sentence)  # predict NER tags

# Print sentence and NER spans
print(sentence)
print('The following NER tags are found:')
# iterate over entities and print
for entity in sentence.get_spans('ner'):
    print(entity)

# Output
# Span [2,3]: "September 1st"   [− Labels: DATE (1.0)]
# Span [4]: "George"   [− Labels: PERSON (1.0)]
# Span [6,7]: "1 dollar"   [− Labels: MONEY (1.0)]
# Span [10,11,12]: "Game of Thrones"   [− Labels: WORK_OF_ART (1.0)
```

### OntoNotes 5.0 Named Entities

1. `PERSON` (People, including fictional)
2. `NORP` (Nationalities or religious or political groups)
3. `FACILITY` (Buildings, airports, highways, bridges, etc.)
4. `ORGANIZATION` (Companies, agencies, institutions, etc.)
5. `GPE` (Countries, cities, states)
6. `LOCATION` (Non-GPE locations, mountain ranges, bodies of water)
7. `PRODUCT` (Vehicles, weapons, foods, etc. (Not services))
8. `EVENT` (Named hurricanes, battles, wars, sports events, etc.)
9. `WORK OF ART` (Titles of books, songs, etc.)
10. `LAW` (Named documents made into laws)
11. `LANGUAGE` (Any named language)
12. `DATE` (Absolute or relative dates or periods)
13. `TIME` (Times smaller than a day)
14. `PERCENT` (Percentage (including “%”))
15. `MONEY` (Monetary values, including unit)
16. `QUANTITY` (Measurements, as of weight or distance)
17. `ORDINAL` (“first”, “second”)
18. `CARDINAL` (Numerals that do not fall under another type)